# Why is my database not deleted?

Tags: linux, mysql, database, command-line-interface

I have seen in several tutorial that the "DROP" command will drop the database, but it is not deleted. Why is my database not deleted ?

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE www_example_com;
Query OK, 645 rows affected (3.36 sec)

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| www_example_com    |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| www_example_com    |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Could you attach the last few lines from `/var/log/mysqld.log` ? It could be possible that a www.example.com folder exists in /var/lib/mysql/ and you do not have access to that folder as `mysql` user.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici There is no log at this location

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici There is this file but it is empty `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Answer (score 1):

Does that database have active connections which are keeping the database from being dropped?

You can see active connections using www_example_com with `mysqladmin processlist -u root -p`.  If you can restart mysql that will fix it the easiest.  If you can't then you need to terminate those connections with `mysqladmin kill <process>`